# VS Code Go to Symbol in Workspace - exclude external files

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Using VSCode is there a way to configure the **Go to Symbol in Workspace** tool (default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to *exclude* external directories?

In my Angular workspace, VS Code is currently listing symbols in *node_modules*, *program files* and other directories I am not interested in searching.

[image]

Researching around the internet I various posts recommended trying the following settings, but setting these did not impact Go to Symbols.

#### `.vscode\settings.json`

```
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/obj": true,
        "*.d.ts": true
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/dist": true,
        "*.d.ts": true
    },
```

#### `\jsconfig.json`

```
   "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
```

Comment: I have found this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46718#issuecomment-599397590 and there is a commit to fix this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0e48f6227991e21244efd6dd3964a5ea12cac687

Comment: Looks like the VS Code team is updating the Go to Symbols to respect `files.exclude`, but it's not in yet?

Comment: Do you find solution? @PhilipPittle

Comment: I stopped looking for a solution - I'm no longer working on an angular app.

Comment: The github issue is open since 2018 and what M$ does instead of fixing this crucial usability bug is literally [adding snake images to the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_image-support) and [turning the IDE into a videoplayer](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_auto-playing-and-looping-for-previewed-videos)

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

1. Go to: File > Preferences > Settings
2. Type in the search field: exclude
3. Add the following under "Files: Exclude": `**/node_modules`
4. And add the following under "Files: Watcher Exclude": `**/node_modules/*/**`

[image]

I hope this is what you are looking for (which works for me)

Comment: Does not work for me with VSCode `1.80.0`